# Use custom standalone-full.xml with arquillian

Tags: java, jboss, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I'm using wildfly container with arquillian for my integration tests.
In some cases, I want to use JMS and standalone-full.xml with some custom configuration is loaded at server start. 
So, for my int tests, I want to load this standalone-full.xml by putting it in src/test/resources.

How can i do that ?

I can't put the following line because it's the default jboss file and not my overrided standalone-full.xml file.

```
<property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
```

When I specify file path (in resources), it doesn't work.

```
<property name="serverConfig">src/test/resources/standalone-full.xml</property>

<property name="serverConfig">/src/test/resources/standalone-full.xml</property>

<property name="serverConfig">${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/standalone-full.xml</property>
```

[EDIT]

When I put maven variable in surefire-plugin like this :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                   <server.standalone.config.path>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/standalone-full.xml</server.standalone.config.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and use it in arquillian.xml

```
<property name="serverConfig">${server.standalone.config.path}</property>
```

I have this error  :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYCTL0214: Could not get main file: 
D:\my_project_path\int-tests/src/test/resources/standalone-full.xml. Specified
 files must be relative to the configuration dir: D:\wildfly_path\wildfly-
10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I used another method because I have multiple modules…
The build process is broken down into three parts.

1. wildfly container deployment

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
       [...]
       <artifactItem>
           <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
       </artifactItem>
   [...]
   <execution>
       <id>stop-test-server</id>
       <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
       <goals>
           <goal>go-offline</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
   [...]
   ```
2. jboss_home and standalone-full.xml

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.19.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <!-- Fork every test because it will launch a separate AS instance -->
           <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
           <systemPropertyVariables>
               <!-- the maven dependency plugin will have already downloaded the server on /target -->
               <jboss.home>${project.build.directory}/${wildfly.test.embedded.folder}</jboss.home>
               <server-config>standalone-full.xml</server-config>
           </systemPropertyVariables>
           <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. resources copy (jms.rar and custom standalone-full.xml

   ```xml
   <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.7</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>copy-configuration-resource</id>
               <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>copy-resources</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${wildfly.test.embedded.folder}/standalone/configuration</outputDirectory>
                   <resources>
                       <resource>
                           <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/wildfly-resources/configuration</directory>
                               <includes>
                                   <include>*.xml</include>
                                   <include>*.properties</include>
                               </includes>
                           </resource>
                       </resources>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>copy-deployment-resource</id>
                   <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${wildfly.test.embedded.folder}/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                       <resources>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/wildfly-resources/deployments</directory>
                           <includes>
                               <include>wmq.jmsra.rar</include>
                           </includes>
                       </resource>
                   </resources>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

and in arquillian.xml:

```xml
<container qualifier="arquillian-wildfly-managed" default="true" mode="suite">
    <configuration>
        <property name="serverConfig">standalone-full.xml</property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

It works fine…

Answer (score 2):

We use the following configuration:

```xml
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources-wildfly-embedded</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.surefire}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <!-- the maven dependency plugin will have already downloaded the server on /target -->
                    <jboss.home>${dir.wildfly.home}</jboss.home>
                    <module.path>${dir.wildfly.modules}</module.path>
                    <!-- Do not use ./test/resources-wildfly/configuration because jboss will write to the
                    config directory and we don't want these files to change -->
                    <jboss.server.config.dir>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/configuration</jboss.server.config.dir>
                    <org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage>UnitTest</org.apache.deltaspike.ProjectStage>
                    <server-config>standalone.xml</server-config>
                </systemPropertyVariables>

                <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Within src/test/resources-wildfly-embedded/configuration we have:

- application-roles.properties
- application-users.properties
- logging.properties
- mgmt-users.properties
- mgmt-groups.properties
- standalone.xml

It seems you need all these files for startup to work but there is no way to put standalone.xml in a different directory than the rest of the config.

Comment: yes, but I have multiple modules, and it not works... But your answer allowed me to find the solution